# Activity Indicator with loop

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm working with an app that has a loop that does a lot of work.  The loop generates a bunch of numbers, and then puts them in to a `UITableView`.  I want to display a `UIActivityIndicatorView` when the work is going on.  I added the activity indicator to the screen and centered it.  At first, I wasn't getting the activity indicator to display at all.  I realized that this was because the activity indicator was running on the same thread as the loop, and that the indicator would never update while the loop was running.  I did some research on how to create a background thread, and came up with this.

```
    self.progressIndicator.startAnimating()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { () -> Void in
        for var instance = 0; instance < numberCount!; instance++ {
            //Lots of work done in here.  Items are added to a
            //collection that is used to populate the table view.
            //Takes around 10 seconds to execute.
        }
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("FinishedNumbers", object: nil)
    });
```

The activity indicator is running on the main thread, and the processing of the loop is running in the background.  I created a notifier that calls out to a function to call reloadList and stop the activity indicator once the list of numbers has completed.

```
func doneWithCreateNumbers(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.numberList.reloadData()
    self.progressIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

While this does work, it doesn't work well.  There are a couple of problems.

Even though the processing of the loop is done in under 10 seconds, it takes much longer for the list to populate and the activity indicator to stop spinning.  I put a breakpoint in the doneWithCreateNumbers function and checked the count of the numbers collection and it does have the correct number of items in it.  After the code to reload the list and stop the activity indicator executes, it takes between 30 and 40 seconds for the list to populate and the activity indicator to stop running.

The list does populate eventually and the indicator goes away, but I get this error message in the debug window:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background
>   thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This
>   will cause an exception in a future release.

I've tried rearranging all of this in a number of ways, but nothing has worked any better than what I have now.  One of the ways that I rearranged it was to put the reloadData and stopAnimating right after the loop.  It didn't work any better, and I still got the error listed above.

I'm missing something here, but not sure what.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView.init(activityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge)
self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

// Switch To Background Thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) { () -> Void in

    // Animate Activity Indicator On Main Thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    })


    // Do your table calculation work here


    // Stop Animating Activity Indicator On Main Thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works perfectly.  I added my tableView.reloadData call to the second main queue, and all problems have been cleared up.  Thanks for taking the time to post this.